# GAS: How to use UrlFetchApp to search private repo via GitHub API, with authentication?

Tags: authentication, github, google-apps-script, basic-authentication, github-api

Am trying to scrape data from a private repo by using GitHub's API via the Google Apps Script (GAS).

I have an accessToken that seems to work for normal things, but when it comes to doing **searches for issues**, the accessToken is not accepted.

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:esaruoho/ztracker_mac+state:open (+aT)

I'm trying to access a private repo (not the one I linked here, which is public, and the link works) and attach the

```
?access_token=token
```

at the end, but for some reason this simply does not seem to work. Is there some other way of authentication?

I'm trying to figure out how I could modify the **UrlFetchApp.fetch** to also input the required **headers** that authenticate, but I'm not figuring out what kind of stuff GitHub authenticates with

Comment: What error code do you get when you try to run your request?

Comment: @Kos
[17-07-25 15:16:35:841 EEST] {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"message":"The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.","resource":"Search","field":"q","code":"invalid"}],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/search/"}

Comment: Check result of call to `https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO`, what does it say?

Comment: @Kos hi, turns out the issue was that the ?access_token= was supposed to be &access_token=  -- once you switch the question mark to an ampersand, everything works beautifully.

Comment: When you generated your access token which scopes did you authorize? I suspect you may need to authorize more scopes on the token before you can use it to do issue searches.

Comment: @DimuDesigns except that if the URL is not supposed to have multiple questionmarks, instead one questionmark - then other questionmarks replaced by ampersand (&) then no matter which types of tokens and scopes I've edited, the fully functioning token is simply not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you are trying to do:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:esaruoho/ztracker_mac+state:open?access_token=yourToken
```

Notice how you already have a question mark (?) in the URL, you can't put two in, you have to change the question mark to an ampersand (&)

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:esaruoho/ztracker_mac+state:open&access_token=yourToken
```